# What does "brought his chair on four legs" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english, dialect

> Pine Billy **brought his chair down on four legs** and spit in the fire and studied the logs a minute.

What does the part in bold mean?

*[The Education of Little Tree](https://books.google.it/books?id=8D477kaES7EC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=%22Pine%20Billy%20brought%20his%20chair%22&source=bl&ots=GmqhSPn1LL&sig=ACfU3U2bCMiy_A1GnApOOkbfqPB9qs3l4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHxM-O-_yDAxWjg_0HHZauAYEQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Pine%20Billy%20brought%20his%20chair%22&f=false)* by Forest Carter

There's more context added below

> “Smokehouse studied the feller and says, 'Ye could be right, Pine Billy. We'll jest have a look.' and he ambles acrost the road to the feller's car.”
> Pine Billy brought his chair down on four legs and spit in the fire and studied the logs a minute. I couldn't hardly wait to hear what happened to the criminal.

Comment: I think "**brought** his chair down … **and spit** in the fire" should be " and **spat** …".

Comment: maybe, it's a novel so there could be ungrammatical sentences.

Comment: The dialogue (and it appears the narration too)  is imitating [Southern American speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English), from what I could make out, the text  is deliberately filled with grammatical errors that I advise you not to copy.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - _'spit' is also sometimes used for the past tense and past participle, especially in North American English._ (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries). Collins Dictionary is more definite: _spit [...] past tense, past participle spat
LANGUAGE NOTE:  In American English, the form spit is used as the past tense and past participle._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people, when they sit in a chair, rock backwards so that the front two legs are off the ground.  Pine Billy was doing this, then he rocked forwards so that the chair is standing on all four legs. ie all four legs of the chair are touching the ground.

There is no indication about why he did it or what it means: it's just a bit of narrative decoration, like spitting in the fire.

Comment: what does "bring down on" mean?

Comment: I understand that sentence mean "He bring down his chair to touch the four legs"

Comment: because on mean touching(i'm korean)

Comment: "ON" in this sentence means "being supported by". The chair is now being supported by all four legs.

Comment: I see, Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Tilting one's chair is usually a sign of feeling relaxed. Probably Billy brought his chair back to the upright position so that he could concentrate on something (he 'studied the logs').

Comment: What @KateBunting said. Also notice that before starting a *physical, outdoor task* (such as chopping wood for the fire), people stereotypically *roll up their sleeves* and *spit **on their hands*** by way of preparing themselves. I find it easy to believe that *spitting **into the fire*** echoes that kind of "get ready to focus on the task in hand" preparatory action.

Comment: Kate Bunting, FumbleFingers, Thanks for comments.